# Huawei In App Purchase : Performing multiple requests in short time leads to an error

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am using Huawei In App Purchase in my application. The problem is when the user makes multiple requests (lets say around 5) to IapClient in short time (lets say around 2 sec) then my application throws an error

My log is below :

```
com.huawei.hms.iap.IapApiException: -1: Core error
   at com.huawei.hms.iap.f.doExecute(IsEnvReadyTaskApiCall.java:1068)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.TaskApiCall.onResponse(TaskApiCall.java:190)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager$1.onCallback(HuaweiApiManager.java:272)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$a.onError(HmsClient.java:134)
   at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:205)
   at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:175)
   at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$a.b(PendingResultImpl.java:490)
   at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$a.handleMessage(PendingResultImpl.java:467)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Is there any limitation on number/frequency of IAP calls? What is your advice in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error** Code -1 means you are  advised to use the obtainOwnedPurchases API to check whether the user  has purchased the product.

**Solution:** Use the obtainOwnedPurchases API to check whether the user has purchased the product.

For a consumable that has been purchased, call the consumeOwnedPurchase API to consume the product after it is delivered. After being consumed, the product can be purchased next time. If the product is a non-consumable product or a subscription, the product cannot be purchased again.

Queries information about all purchased in-app products, including consumables, non-consumables, and auto-renewable subscriptions.

If the information about consumables is returned, the consumables might not be delivered due to some exceptions. In this case, your app needs to check whether the consumables are delivered. If not, the app needs to deliver them and calls the consumeOwnedPurchase API to consume them.
If the information about non-consumables is returned, the non-consumables do not need to be consumed.
If the information about subscriptions is returned, all existing subscription relationships of the user in the app are returned.

If purchaseState is **0** that means product is **PURCHASED**.

If purchaseState is **1** that means product is **CANCELED**.

If purchaseState is **2** that means product is **PURCHASED**.

**Code:**

```
public void checkUserOwnedTheProduct(final Context context) {
    OwnedPurchasesReq ownedPurchasesReq = new OwnedPurchasesReq();
    ownedPurchasesReq.setPriceType(productType);
    Task<OwnedPurchasesResult> task = Iap.getIapClient(context).obtainOwnedPurchases(ownedPurchasesReq);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<OwnedPurchasesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(OwnedPurchasesResult result) {
            // Obtain the execution result.
            if (result != null && result.getInAppPurchaseDataList() != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.getInAppPurchaseDataList().size(); i++) {
                    String inAppPurchaseData = result.getInAppPurchaseDataList().get(i);
                    String inAppSignature = result.getInAppSignature().get(i);
                    boolean success = CipherUtil.doCheck(inAppPurchaseData, inAppSignature, Key.getPublicKey());
                    if (success) {
                        try {
                            InAppPurchaseData inAppPurchaseDataBean = new InAppPurchaseData(inAppPurchaseData);
                            int purchaseState = inAppPurchaseDataBean.getPurchaseState();                            

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (productType == IapClient.PriceType.IN_APP_NONCONSUMABLE) {
                    ((HmsInAppPurchaseList) context).loadList();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof IapApiException) {
                IapApiException apiException = (IapApiException) e;
                Status status = apiException.getStatus();
                int returnCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
            } else {
                // Other external errors
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For More Information you can visit these links:

**In-App Purchase Article:**

**Client Side:** https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201255229704010231&fid=0101187876626530001

**Server Side:** https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201273064244120101&fid=0101187876626530001

**In-App Purchase Github Link:**

**Client Side:** https://github.com/DTSE-India-Community/HMS-In-App-Purchase-Kit

**Server Side:** https://github.com/DTSE-India-Community/Huawei-In-App-Purchase-And-Push-Kit-Server_Side-Implementation

Answer (score 1):

The error code you are getting is -1
In the official documentation, the solution is described as

> If this error code is returned during the purchase request, you are  advised to use the obtainOwnedPurchases API to check whether the user  has purchased the product.

Documentation : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/iap-ExceptionHandlingAndGeneralErrorCodes-v4

Network requests in the IAP service are processed in asynchronous mode.

The process from checking whether the service is available to completing a transaction is processed according to the steps. These steps must be performed in sequence. Each step contains exception handling.

If an exception occurs in one step and is not handled, the next step cannot be performed. my advise is follow the purchase process and carefully process the result of each step to complete a transaction and ensure good user experience.

and please call

```
isEnvReady()
```

task to be sure IAP environment is ready to make a purchase every time when you are purchasing something.